# Reshape a NumPy array based on values in its columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

What is the most compact way to make a matrix from a table with `numpy`?
I have a table of values, where 1st column is `x`, 2nd is `y` and 3rd is `z`. `z` values are all unique, `(x, y)` pair is obtained with combinations of `x` and `y`. Here is an example:

```
0.0 0.0 949219540.0
0.0 0.5 944034910.0
0.0 1.0 938508543.0
0.0 1.5 930093905.0
0.0 2.0 922076484.0
50.0 0.0 911497861.0
50.0 0.5 903224763.0
50.0 1.0 900406431.0
50.0 1.5 890658529.0
50.0 2.0 880907404.0
100.0 0.0 883527077.0
100.0 0.5 911683042.0
........ # and so on
```

basically this is a matrix `5x9`:

```
0.0   0.0   0.5   1.0   1.5   2.0
0.0   0.949 0.944 0.939 0.93  0.922
50.0  0.911 0.903 0.9   0.891 0.881
100.0 0.884 0.912 0.84  0.839 0.851
150.0 0.85  0.84  0.799 0.844 0.863
200.0 0.84  0.79  0.806 0.847 0.745
250.0 0.789 0.78  0.748 0.719 0.759
300.0 0.761 0.783 0.714 0.766 0.698
350.0 0.737 0.757 0.792 0.705 0.665
400.0 0.801 0.797 0.57  0.628 0.532
```

Now for this i making: `set(x)` and `set(y)` to get rid of duplicates, `reshape(Z)` with length of `x` any `y` and then `vstack` and `hstack` to concatenate `x, y, z`. I belief that this is quite common operation in data processing, and maybe it has one-step-solution. More over, my way is not good when `x` and `y` are not in order, so `set()` can broke a matrix logic.

Comment: Do you have pandas? This is a one liner with pandas.

Comment: I would like to see pandas solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically the opposite of `numpy.meshgrid`.
For a one-liner, you can use `scipy.interpolate.griddata`:

```
grid = griddata(list(zip(x, y)), z, 
                (x.reshape((len(set(y)), len(set(x)))),
                 y.reshape((len(set(y)), len(set(x))))), 
                method='nearest')
```

Longer demonstration: let's say that we have an list of entries that cover completely a matrix. In `numpy`, this is obtained by `meshgrid`

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(0, 5)

In [3]: b = np.arange(6, 9)

In [4]: aa, bb = np.meshgrid(a, b)
```

And assign values to each element of the mesh:

```
IN [5]: x, y = aa.flatten(), bb.flatten()

In [6]: z = np.ones(len(x))
```

These are the starting x, y, and z of the OP.
Now let's use grid data to get all values into a matrix. `griddata` is much more powerful than this, but having only one point per grid and a clearly equally spaced grid, the matrix comes out exact.

```
In [7]: points = list(zip(x, y))

In [8]: from scipy.interpolate import griddata

In [9]: grid = griddata(points, z, 
                        (x.reshape((len(set(y)), len(set(x)))),
                         y.reshape((len(set(y)), len(set(x))))), 
                        method='nearest')

In [10]: grid
Out[10]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

In [11]: a, b = set(x), set(y)

In [12]: np.hstack((np.concatenate(([0], b)).reshape((1, len(b) + 1)).T, np.vstack((a, grid))))
Out[12]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 7.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 8.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that is not exactly what i need. I need z matrix with x and y on rows and columns.

Comment: I edited the answer to give you the indices (element 0-0 is somewhat arbitrary anyway)! :)
The solution with pandas is probably cleaner, but this allows you to avoid an additional dependency (as pandas would require scipy anyway)

Comment: Thanks, though this is not so clean as i expected, it looks like this is the most compact way to do what i need with numpy.